# How to get control id if control is rendered inside of master page with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, master-pages

I went through some posts here but could not find exactly what I'm looking for.

My control is rendered the following way:

```
ctl00_ctl00_Contentplaceholder2_ContentPlaceHolder2_txtAccountNum0
```

How can I reference it using jQuery?

The following does not work:

```
$('#<%=txtAccountNum0.ClientID%>')
```

Comment: You are probably missing the `#` for the ID selector.

Comment: Sorry, actually, I have it, just mispelled

Comment: I also tried the following: `var t = $('#<%=Master.FindControl("txtAccountNum0").ClientID%>').val()` and it did not work either

Comment: Can you be more specific about what doesn't work, then? If your javascript is in a separate code file, the `<%=` reference probably won't work. Have you logged `<%=txtAccountNum0.ClientID%>` to see that you're getting the selector you think you're getting?

Comment: When executing `alert($('<%=txtAccountNum0.ClientID%>')`, it displays `[object Objec]`. When executing `alert($('<%=txtAccountNum0.ClientID%>').val()`, it displays `undefined` I think the problem is in how the control is rendered: `ctl00_ctl00_Contentplaceholder2_ContentPlaceHolder2_txtAccountNum0`. If it is rendered only through master page it should be rendered this way: `ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ txtAccountNum0`. But it is not the case. There is another placeholder there, which I think needs to be accessed too, in order to access control itself

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need a `#` before the ID. I do that all the time.